# How to cite when the author's name is a number?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I tried to cite the first answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52014/is-being-finitely-generated-a-local-property) question but failed. 
I used the entry generated by the site, i.e.,

```
@MISC {52022,
TITLE = {Is being finitely generated a local property?},
AUTHOR = {14555 (https://mathoverflow.net/users/12208/14555)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow},
NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/52022 (version: 2011-01-15)},
EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/52022},
URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/52022}
}
```

BibTeX reported nothing but LaTeX returned error: Missing \endcsname inserted. As you can see, the name of the author is a string of numbers. I tried to replace the author's name with some letters and there was no error in this case.

How should I cite this answer then? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Just for sanity / readability, I'd probably cite the author as `Username "14555"` or something like that, to avoid confusing the reader.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you. I used “Anonymous” as an ad-hoc solution but I think yours is much better.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: @Mico I use "amsref" package and the document class is report. With "amsref", one does not need to specify the bibliography style, as ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf states. I assume the style is similar to amsplain.